# Delay onChange javascript function long enough for another javascript to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, onchange

I have 3 select boxes with an onChange function to call a script to add all 3 values and put them in a hidden field. The problem is there is another script changing the boxes depending on  the value of the others. Script 2 saves the values before script 1 finishes changing the values of the select options.

Script 1 Updates the day value based off year and month value

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $().ready(function () { 
        $().dateSelectBoxes($('#release_month'),$('#release_day'),$('#release_year'),true);
    });
</script>
```

Script 2 Grabs all 3 dates and make 1 complete date. Problem is, this does this before script 1 updates the day.

```
<script>
     function datepopulate(){
    var day = document.getElementById('release_day').value.substr(-2);
    var month = document.getElementById('release_month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('release_year').value;
   var completedate = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
   document.getElementById('releasedate_value').value = completedate;
      alert(document.getElementById('releasedate_value').value);
   return true;
}

</script>
```

Script 2 is called like this. while script 1 is is automatic

```
<select onChange="datepopulate();"> </select>
```

Comment: So `dateSelectBoxes` internally wires up to the change event of the items?

Comment: Why are you using all traditional JavaScript in your second script if you are using jQuery? IMHO this: `$('#release_day').val().substr(-2)` is easier (faster to type) than: `document.getElementById('release_day').value.substr(-2);`.

Comment: @Tejs yea it uses a jquery script

Comment: @Craig I suggest you put your complete code (HTML and Javascript) in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You could attach the jquery .change() event with the datepopulate() function as a callback to the select box and chain the logic in your .ready(...) section.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you simply need to expose a callback from your jQuery plugin to do extra logic after the click event code has fired. So you would have something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $().ready(function () { 
        $().dateSelectBoxes($('#release_month'),$('#release_day'),$('#release_year'),true, function()
            {
                // Do Stuff after this plugin does its stuff
            });
    });
</script>
```

It sounds like you've wired up two events to the change event, and since it's not going to be deterministic what event is fired first, you're having synchronization problems. If you can enforce this by ordering the events via a callback mechanism, then the problem should be solved.

EDIT: To turn your code into jQuery, it's actually pretty simple. This would be the jQuery version:

```
var date = $('#release_year').val() + "-" + $('#release_month').val() + "-" + $('#release_day').val();

$('#releasedate_value').val(date);
```

The `val()` function will return the queried elements value. Since you're selecting by Id, this means you will effectively get the `value` of the element back. You then string concatenate and assign it to your hidden value with the same method, but with the value as the parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I like your idea here; however i'm not very familiar with jquery. How would i translate my regular javascript into jquery here?

Answer (score 0):

Add a function argument to dateSelectBoxes, so it will call datepopulate itself instead of the onchange.

```
 $().ready(function () { 
    $().dateSelectBoxes($('#release_month'),$('#release_day'),$('#release_year'),true, datepopulate);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use timeout to wait in JavaScript for an event to finish. The only way to be sure something is done is with a callback, have no doubts about that or you'll just run into more trouble

Try this though:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $.dateSelectBoxes($('#release_month'),$('#release_day'),$('#release_year'),true);
    $("select").on("change", function(){
            var day = document.getElementById('release_day').value.substr(-2),
        month = document.getElementById('release_month').value,
        year = document.getElementById('release_year').value,
        completedate = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
        if(day > 0 && month > 0 && year > 0){
            document.getElementById('releasedate_value').value = completedate;
            alert(document.getElementById('releasedate_value').value);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

However, the 'right' way to do it, is to have a button `<input type=button style="display:none">` then on change you check to see that every select box has a value of != 0. Then if all are selected you do `$("button").css("display", "block");` then

```
$("button").on('click', function(){
    var day = document.getElementById('release_day').value.substr(-2),
    month = document.getElementById('release_month').value,
    year = document.getElementById('release_year').value;
    document.getElementById('releasedate_value').value = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
    alert(document.getElementById('releasedate_value').value);
});
```

Comment: This way, the end user can change the dates as many times as they want to get it right, so it doesn't commit a bad date that they miss-clicked, and need to reset.

Comment: I see, however if the button isn't click when the user hits the save button nothing will be saved?

Comment: that doesnt make sense, how is the button not clicked if they hit the 'save' button... doesn't 'hit' mean 'click'?

Comment: So basically if all three date drop downs aren't selected, the button basically does nothing, if all three are selected, it saves.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to point out that there are times when this will not work properly (as of jQuery 1.7):

```
$('#element').html(some_really_large_value);
console.log($('#element').html());
```

There are times when the DOM updates do not block function execution, and what will appear in console will be the previous content of #element.

If this is the case in the above example, then even adding a callback to $.dateSelectBoxes may not solve the problem. If this still does not return the correct value:

```
$.dateSelectBoxes( ... $('#release_month') ... , function(){
   console.log($('#release_month').val());
});
```

Then the only solution I know of is to add a race condition:

```
$.dateSelectBoxes( ... $('#release_month') ... , function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ console.log($('#release_month').val()) }, 100);
});
```

[UPDATE]

I'm recently finding out that the problem here is not that the .html() method isn't blocking function execution, but that the browser is grouping DOM updates by function scope (or something like that, am a bit fuzzy on the details).

This means that jQuery DOM updates with .html() and .val(), do block, but they only block as far as scheduling the DOM update with the browser. Thus even wrapping the DOM read in a setTimeout( fn, 1) will solve the problem.

BTW, this is exactly the kind of thing [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) was designed to solve.

Comment: I'm a little confused is the above function suppose to slow down the release month?

Comment: it supposed to delay the callback function on $.dateSelectBoxes until after it has completed updating the DOM. something like https://github.com/m-gagne/limit.js may also do the trick.